# Realtime PHP Function

Tags: php, flush

I have script that take between 5 - 10 sec to completly loading .

I try to make it with for and ob_flush but it show the outputs only at the end and no at real time .

```
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ ){
    // **
    echo "\n[-] Tracker mode (ON): Waiting the user to get online...\n";
    $wa->SendPresenceSubscription($dst);
    $wa->PollMessages();

    if($presence == "available"){
        echo "- The user is now online\n\n";
    } else {
        echo "- The user is offline\n\n";
        $wa->sendGetRequestLastSeen($dst);
    }
    // **
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

the marks ** its my script : 5 - 10 seconds to loading each other..

Comment: If you want to produce output as it is generated, remove output buffering. Eliminate `flush()`, `ob_flush()` and `ob_start()` (not shown in your code snippet).

Comment: @artjomb Syntax errors, even seemingly unrelated ones, are often relevant to the solution. Is there a reason that you edited the code?

Comment: You'd be far better off using ajax polling for this. It is cleaner and leaves you in control of what you display when on the client side. For example it might be that the browser itself or some proxy inbetween buffers the output...

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I've understood that the OP added `**` to mark his own code (assuming the flush/sleep is copied from somewhere). If you think this is not it, you may rollback the edit. I've only wanted to make the code more readable and remove the unnecessary syntax errors.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for all ! ,
Its right , my code is only at php and in ** . @GeorgeCummins I dont understand what I need to do . can u help me ?
Thanks !